# Static wifi configuration using /etc/network/interfaces.d and wpa_supplicant

Tags: debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- Having two different local on the same network ips for Wifi and Ethernet, respectively on a GUI-less Debian Buster 10.10.

Ethernet is working, but wpa_supplicant keeps crashing. I'm trying to follow the instructions on [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant).

```
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:72:c7:ad:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.30/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21d:72ff:fec7:ad43/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:3b:4e:88:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Content of `/etc/network/interfaces.d/enp2s0`:

```
#custom configuration
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.30/24
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Content of `etc/network/interfaces.d/wlps40`

```
allow-hotplug wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet static
        wpa-ssid SSID_NAME_WITHOUT_QUOTES
        wpa-psk PSK_HASH_OBTAINED_FROM_WPA_SUPPLICANT_WITHOUT_QUOTES

        address 192.168.1.31
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Content of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid=SSID_NAME_INSIDE_DOUBLE_QUOTES
    #psk="PSK_IN_PLAIN_TEXT"
    psk=PSK_HASH
}
```

Then created the [wpa-supplicant](/questions/tagged/wpa-supplicant) service and restarted it as instructed by the wiki page.
Then the command :
`$ sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlp4s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
I get this response :

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

Journalctl is yelling: wrong key, but my gut is telling me that there are errors config-file wise on top of that.

Any help will be much appreciated.

## update

Moved and renamed `/etc/network/interfaces.d/enp2s0`

Edited `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlp4s0` as follows

```
#wlp4s0 custom configuration
allow-hotplug wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.31
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        pre-up wpa_supplicant -i wlp4s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log
```

Replaced the hash of the [psk](/questions/tagged/psk) with plain text.
Deleted `/run/wpa_supplicant/wlp4s0` and restarted the [wpa-supplicant](/questions/tagged/wpa-supplicant) service.
Now I am able to connect to the internet using the wireless device.

I ran `sudo ifdown wlp4sO` to bring the device down and see if I can bring it up, again.
`if up wlp4s0` succeeds after deleting `/run/wpa_supplicant/`

Comment: My money is on your wifi hardware not working with `wext`, which is why leaving out this option fixed it. (BTW, you can also answer your own question).